# Django image not loading Page not Found Error

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I'm new to Django and I'm facing a problem of loading a static file (image). I got

> `127.0.0.1/:1707 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/static/images/background/1.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

I'm pretty sure that the problem is on the path but I can't understand where this /static/css/ comes from. Could you please help me?

My settings.py file:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'evillio/static')
]
```

My index.html file:

```
<!-- First Page with Picture and Search Starts -->
    <section class="home-one home1-overlay **home1_bgi1**">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row posr">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="home_content">
                        <div class="home-text text-center">
                            <h2 class="fz55">Find Your Dream Home</h2>
                            <p class="fz18 color-white">From as low as $10 per day with limited time offer discounts.</p>
                        </div>
```

My CSS file:

```
home1_bgi1{
  background-image: url('static/images/background/1.jpg');
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 960px;
```

When inspecting the page

[image: Inspect]

Answer (score 0):

Did you include {% load static %} at the top ??

For the latest version of Django, it doesn't use that in Setting.py:

```
`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'evillio/static')
]`
```

Instead of this for Django 3.1 change code as bellow:

```
`STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    '/var/www/static/',
]`
```

Read the documentation of Django 3.1, it has some code updated in the previous version of Django.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/